# parallel optimization pyomo-gurobi

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, threadpoolexecutor, pyomo

I am fairly new to Pyomo and optimization. I am trying to solve an iterated local search algorithm where I have to solve "relatively small" optimization problems several times. At the moment, I have implemented a loop where each time, I formulate the optimization problem and solve it with Gurobi. However, I was wondering if there is a "parallelized" way to deal with that, since results from the local searches are not affecting each other. I have looked into both the ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor. The first one does not improve the speed, while the second gives me some error. Do you have any suggestion? These are a few lines of code just to give an idea. Thanks.

```
def task(input)
   ###optimization formulation
     #optimization solver (gurobi)
   return (result_optimization)

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        future_task={executor.submit(task,number): number for number i list_local_searches}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_task):
            results_local_searches.append(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into licensing issues, depending on your Gurobi license. With my academic license, I am currently only able to run one Gurobi process per machine at a time.

There is a site license available which may be able to obviate this issue, but you are beholden to the powers that be to set it up correctly.